# How can I make a MenuBar app (using Swift) that has more than just a list of menu items?

Tags: macos, swift

I'm new to OSX development (I've done a little iOS stuff, but this is my first OSX app, and my first Swift app).

I've found several tutorials for how to make a MenuBar app with just a simple list of menu items, like the following:

[image: simple menu]

But I'm looking for something more like Evernote's, or Google Drive's, or Mint's MenuBar window:

[image: window]

I believe that to do something like the latter, I need a regular NSWindow that is just toggled by clicking the status item (right?), but how do I go about positioning the window the way Evernote & Google do?

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301701/how-to-get-the-on-screen-location-of-an-nsstatusitem) that gives a couple of ways to get the status item position, if using an Objective C app, but I'm not sure how to translate that to a Swift app.  For example, one answer suggests using the following to get the frame of the status item after clicking on it:

```
[[[NSApp currentEvent] window] frame]
```

but, in Swift, NSApp.currentEvent does not have a member named "window"...

Does anyone know of any example MenuBar apps, written in Swift, that have more than just a simple list of menu items?  Is such a thing simply not possible with Swift, yet?

***UPDATE:***
Since the examples and starter apps that do this kind of thing in Objective C are abundant, and there's little or nothing on how to do it in Swift, I ended up abandoning the Swift route and built an Objective C app, instead.  I used this one as a starter: https://github.com/shpakovski/Popup.  It was very quick/easy to get started and ended up being a lot less work than a Swift app would have been.

Maybe one day when Swift is more mature, I'll try another one in that language.

Comment: Hopefully Swift 2 will deliver your request...

Comment: @troy, can you link to those tutorials you found about the mac apps with the "simple list of menu items"?

Comment: @DeveloperACE, it was long enough ago that I don't have the specific tutorials anymore.  A google search for "Swift MenuBar app" will bring up a bunch though.

Comment: @Troy thank you. I think I managed to find some good ones that I linked to in my recent commit names for my github project: www.github.com/DeveleoperACE/TinyReminders

Comment: [This 2017 article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/165853/menus-popovers-menu-bar-apps-macos) explains in detail how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `NSApplication.sharedApplication().currentEvent?.window` seems fine.